# iOS launch screen will appear in portrait instead of landscape

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, launch-screen, uideviceorientation

I am creating an iOS app that will support iPhone and iPad in landscape and portrait orientations. I have setup my launch screen storyboard with an ImageView and that appears correctly in both landscape and portrait modes in Interface Builder. However, even though I am holding my phone in landscape, the launch screen will always appear in portrait. I have logged my device current orientation in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but it reports UIDeviceOrientation unknown. After the launch screen disappears, the first view appears in landscape as expected.

Do you know why that happens and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen on both iPhones and iPads or only iPhones?

Comment: Only the device an iPhone 5c which runs iOS 10

Comment: Just tested on an iPhone 7 simulator and works as expected. Maybe this is an iOS 10.3 issue?

Comment: Could you please provide the project through github? Actually there is nothing much to do to put the launchscreen in landscape mode.

Comment: I think I will just leave this for now as the project will be released for iOS 11+...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't open this:[image]

Comment: The device is not locked unfortunately